# Pick and keyof throwing parsing errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I'm trying to convert a class component to TS, for one of my onChange methods, and I was running into this error

> Argument of type '{ [x: number]: any; }' is not
> assignable to parameter of type 'myState | Pick<myState, keyof
> myState>

one of the solutions was to implement this

```
interface myState {
    programTypeId: string
};

switchGeneric = (name: any, id: any) => {
    this.setState({ [name]: id } as Pick<myState, keyof myState>);
};

onChange={id => {
    this.switchGeneric('programTypeId', id);
}};
```

but I seem to get compile errors when trying to use "as keyof", is this a configuration error?

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Please include minimal, complete, reproducible example code

Comment: thanks for the response! turns out it was an eslint config error on my end

Answer (score 0):

turns out it was eslint config error, resolved by added this to my package.json file

```
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  }
```